# Hensel's lemma requires the valuation to be discrete

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, hensels-lemma

In Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, the formulation of Hensel's Lemma (Proposition 4.6 in Chapter II) does not require the valuation to be discrete, only nonarchimedean (unless I somehow missed the requirement).

Following the proof, I used the representation of an element $x \in \mathcal{O}$ as $x = u \pi^n$, which holds when the valuation is discrete.
The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#General_statement) also states the lemma for discrete valuations only.

My question is: It the discreteness of the valuation necessary? If so, is it assumed in the book that every valuation is discrete from this point on?

I have found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20297) where it is explained that nondiscrete valuations are often omitted in some branches of mathematics, so it would make sense for Neukirch to only consider discrete valuations but again, I have not seen this mentioned.

Comment: It's *Hensel*'s lemma

Comment: Presumably you have Neukirch's book to hand. So looking at his proof, it is valid for non-discrete valuations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was there a step in the proof in Neukirch (which did not assume discreteness) that you did not understand?  Note that the $\pi$ in Neukirch's proof is *not* a choice of prime element in $\mathcal O$.  It is a number of largest absolute value among the coefficients in two polynomials whose coefficients are all in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O$ (so necessarily $|\pi| < 1$). I agree it can look misleading to see powers of a number written as $\pi$, since that *suggests* $\pi$ is a prime element of $\mathcal O$, but nowhere does he need the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O$ to be generated by $\pi$.

Another book with a formulation of Hensel's lemma in the form you see in Neurkich is Theorem 4.1 in Dwork, Gerotto, and Sullivan's "An Introduction to $G$-Functions". They work in a complete non-archimedean valued field with no assumption of discreteness and their proof is *different* from the one in Neurkirch, using the contraction mapping theorem on a space of polynomials of bounded degree and no powers of a specially chosen element to create power series in polynomials of bounded degree. Their form of Hensel's lemma is *more general* than what is in Neukirch: instead of assuming $f \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak p$ and that there are polynomials $g_0$ and $h_0$ in $\mathcal O[x]$ such that $f \equiv g_0h_0 \bmod \mathfrak p$ where $\gcd(g_0 \bmod \mathfrak p,h_0 \bmod \mathfrak p) = 1$ in $(\mathcal O/\mathfrak p)[x]$, they assume that there are polynomials $g_0$ and $h_0$ in $\mathcal O[x]$ such that$|f - g_0h_0|_{\rm Gauss} < |R(g_0,h_0)|^2$, where $|F|_{\rm Gauss}$ for a polynomial $F$ is the maximal absolute value of the coefficients of $F$.  The version of Hensel's lemma in Neukirch is the special case of the version in DGS where $R(g_0,h_0) \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak p$ (equivalently, $|R(g_0,h_0)|_{\rm Gauss} = 1$). These two versions of Hensel's lemma are analogous to the two standard versions of Hensel's lemma in the formulation about lifting a root: (i) there is $\alpha_0 \in \mathcal O$ such that $f(\alpha_0) \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak p$ and $f'(\alpha_0) \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak p$ compared to (ii) there is $\alpha_0 \in \mathcal O$ such that $|f(\alpha_0)| < |f'(\alpha_0)|^2$, with (i) being the special case where $|f'(\alpha_0)| = 1$. (A root-lifting version of Hensel's lemma is a special case of a  factorization-lifting version of Hensel's lemma by taking one polynomial in the factorization to be monic and linear: if $F(x) = (x - \alpha_0)h(x)$ then $R(x-\alpha_0,h(x)) = h(\alpha_0) = F'(\alpha_0)$.)

The proof of Hensel's lemma in Borevich and Shafarevich's "Number Theory" (p. 273) is a factorization-lifting theorem as in Neukirch, but their framework is more restrictive than Neukirch's in one sense (their nonarchimedean absolute value is *discrete*) and more general than Neukirch's in another sense (their hypothesis involves resultants rather than a relatively prime factorization mod $\mathfrak p$).

Comment: Thanks! I got the fact that $\pi$ is not a prime element but I thought that the base case of the induction, i.e showing that $f \equiv g_0h_0 \bmod \pi$, would require writing every coefficient as $u\Pi^m$ with $\Pi$ a prime element. I see now that this is not the case. I'll be sure to check the references.